# Python Web Scraping with multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-multithreading

**i want to make a CMS checker for wordpress, i wrote this but my code is very slow :(**

**How I can make it faster?**

```
import requests
import re
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

init(convert=True)


with open("urls.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
sites = [x.strip() for x in content]

for i in range(len(sites)):
    try:
        response = requests.get("http://" + sites[i])
        result =  bool(re.search(r"wp-json",response.text))
        if result == True:
            print(Fore.GREEN +sites[i])
            f= open("Wordpress.txt","a+")
            f.write("http://"+sites[i]+"\n")
            f.close()

        else:
            print(Fore.RED +sites[i])
    except:
        print(response)
```

Comment: you can use standard modules `threading` or `multiprocessing` or search special versions of `requests` which use `theading`, `multiprocessing` or `async`

Comment: BTW: you could learn to use `for url in sites:`

Comment: ie. [toolbelt](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/threading.html) - it is `requests + threading`

Comment: ie. [requests-async](https://github.com/encode/requests-async)

Comment: @furas Hmm , TnQ for help

Comment: BTW: instead of `result =  bool(re.search(...))` and `if result == True` you can try without `bool()` and even without `== True' because it should use it automatically - `result =  re.search(...)` and `if result:`.

Comment: for simple string you can use `if "wp-json" in response.text:` without `re.search`